# Php Redirecting is messed up

Tags: php, redirect

A file redirects to this file which contains:

```
<?
if(!session_id()) {
session_start();
if (strlen($_SESSION['login']) < 1)
die("you're not logged in!");
}
$changer = $_POST['form1'];
switch($changer) {
case 'write':
header("Location: http://teachertechtutor.com/php/learn/kinder/write.php");
break;

case 'read':
header("Location: http://teachertechtutor.com/php/learn/kinder/read.php");
break;

case 'math':
header("Location: http://teachertechtutor.com/php/learn/kinder/math.php");
break;
}
?>
```

but when this one redirects it adds a weird thing like for the math one:
http://teachertechtutor.com/redirects/kinder.php?math=Math%21

why does it add the whole redirects thing...?
redirects/kinder.php?math=Math%21 should be php/learn/kinder/math.php

Comment: this script will not add a `%21` to the urls. Check if you've got mod_rewrite or something messing around with the urls, which is completely out out of php's contorl.

Answer (score 0):

```
%21
```

Stands for an exclamation point in html.
[URL Encoding Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Since this is redirecting to the kinder.php file, this is more than likely an issue with the  .htaccess file causing all of your URLS to redirect to the kinder.php file.

Take a look in your .htaccess file for any code containing "kinder.php" to locate the issue. As far as adjusting it, if you are able to post the .htaccess code, I would be more than happy to assist.